# jQuery possible optimize custom hover code

Tags: jquery

I have a menu and each list item gets a different color border on hover. It works but it feels clunky. How can i optimize this code so I don't repeat so much.

```js
$('ul>li:first-child>a').hover(function() {
  $(this).css('border-bottom', '0.2em solid blue');
}, function() {
  $(this).css('border-bottom', '0');
})

$('ul>li:nth-child(2)>a').hover(function() {
  $(this).css('border-bottom', '0.2em solid green');
}, function() {
  $(this).css('border-bottom', '0');
})

$('ul>li:last-child>a').hover(function() {
  $(this).css('border-bottom', '0.2em solid yellow');
}, function() {
  $(this).css('border-bottom', '0');
})
```

```css
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Blue</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Green</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Yellow</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295692/4076315 - You might get more help if you include your attempt at optimization and describe where you got stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this entirely by using CSS and HTML. Just add class to your list elements and target them using CSS style.

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li class="blue"><a href="#">Blue</a></li>
  <li class="green"><a href="#">Green</a></li>
  <li class="yellow"><a href="#">Yellow</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.blue a:hover{
    color:#0000ff;
}
.green a:hover {
    color:#00ff00;
}
.yellow a:hover {
    color:#ffff00;
}
```

Check the Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/rnjr1aL9/

Edit: I have CSS for text color but you can target different things like border-color, font-size, etc.